# How to prevent states from propagating?

Tags: state, gstreamer, pipeline

Dear GStreamer community.
I am struggling, trying to desynchronise parts of my pipeline.

I am trying to prevent an element from propagating its states change to parent. I know there is a gst_element_set_locked_state which could help, but the issue is that I need to have my component able to handle its own states change (I don't trigger them manually).

The idea would be to unlock -> gst_element_set_state -> lock everytime this is needed, but unfortunatly, the set_state is going to the parent bin.

How should I handle this ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Alann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is misleading.
Locking state doesn't actually locks states ... It prevents state changes notifications from child <-> parent.